# addPreferencesFromResources, Can't figure it out

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent

Well first of all, sorry I made this post, I know there are others like this and I tried to use them but I can't get it to work.

I am using the book "Hello, Android", the third edition, and I stumbled upon the deprecation of the `addPreferencesFromResources()` method. So I tried to fix it, but for some reason I can't get it to work correctly.
I have several classes that I believe are used here:

Prefs java class

```java
package com.example.sudoku; 

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;

public class Prefs extends PreferenceActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new                 MyPreferenceFragment()).commit();
    }
}
```

```java
public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
    }
}
```

This one is copied from one of the other posts, but as I said, I can't get it to work and I don't know why.

Furthermore I have the settings.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" > 
<CheckBoxPreference
    android:key="music" 
    android:title="@string/music_title" 
    android:summary="@string/music_summary" 
    android:defaultValue="true" />
<CheckBoxPreference
    android:key="hints" 
    android:title="@string/hints_title" 
    android:summary="@string/hints_summary" 
    android:defaultValue="true" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

And also a little part of my Sudoku java class that calls for the activity with Prefs.class:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) { 
        case R.id.settings:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Prefs.class));
            return true;
        // More items go here (if any) ... 
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it already, all I had to do was implement the view from the settings.xml file as the content of the Prefs class, , although I couldn't use CheckBoxPreference and I had to use a CheckBox, I'm still very happy about it.